# Limit downloads from App Store by Apple ID

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there a way how to publish an app to App Store but say that only few apple IDs can download this app? Or is there some other distribution option? The app is only for small amount of people and should not be distributed publicly...

Comment: Please review [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+limited+distribution+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of different options:

**1) "Public/Official" App Store**

Your app will be visible (!) on the official App Store and technically anyone can download your app, but you limit the "access" to the functionality of your app with a login. Then you can distribute logins to the people you want to have access to the app. There's a slight chance that Apple might reject your app, but I've seen tones of apps doing this and get approved

**2) "Customer B2B" App Store**

As already mentioned, the recommended way by Apple is the VPP https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/ There are also a couple of providers of "custom enterprise" stores like https://www.mobileiron.com/ etc.

**3) Beta Testing**

You can also distribute your apps with best testing services like Hockey or TestFlight. Unfortunately TestFlight builds expire [after 60 days](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html). Hockey builds expire once your [provisioning profile expires](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/expiration-of-ios-and-os-x-builds), which makes both options not ideal depending on your needs.()

I'd go rather with option 1 or 2. The first one might be the simplest and fastest solution. The second one the "official" one.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

If you want to publish an app to a small amount of people you have other solutions:

- TestFlight
- Fabric

For this solutions you will need people email and the app will not be on the App Store.

The last solution is to provide a password/login system in your app (or lock code or something like that). But maybe apple will reject your app

Comment: the guy in comment told me about B2B so there might be other option :-) https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/